# Simple online search engine service

Tags: web-apps, search-engine

My title is a little bit imprecise since I do not exactly know what the service is called that I am looking for. Basically I am looking for a ready-to use online web service or self-hosted web application with a simple search functionality:

- Enter data in the backend. Could be a table-like data structure with several columns and rows
- A simple user search interface where user can enter a search term and based on the data in the backend the user gets a data output.

**Example**

The backend contains:

```
program|folder

foo|config/
foo|specs/
bar|man/
```

If the user now searches for `config`, he gets `foo` as an output.

Nothing more, nothing less!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an XML file as your backend data... and then search through that data via javascript+jquery.

I asked a question for searching a string in XML some time ago, and got the [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652790/how-to-append-if-found-and-replace-if-not-found-at-all-xml-find-each-loop).

... As for the Entering the data in Backend, you can use Microsoft Office [Excel 2010 to create tables and rows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/create-an-xml-data-file-and-xml-schema-file-from-worksheet-data-HA010263509.aspx), and then assign a format for the xml, and then export the xml from within MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) does?

You would import your data as a JSON, TSV, or CSV file by going to your index and clicking Add Records, Upload File. The search bar on the home page for your index should do exactly what you want, and you can tweak it to your heart's content, or use search widgets provided by Algolia, or just call their API.